# SUOD Model gives ValueError: Input Contains Nan

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, data-science

I am running SUOD from pyod which is ensemble method and received this error.
The models that I am running are Iforest, COPOD and ECOD.

Running these models individually does not say that the data has nan values in it. Also I have already verified if any of the columns has nan values and it does not have any. The data is one hot encoded

```
[Parallel(n_jobs=2)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 2 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=2)]: Done   2 out of   2 | elapsed:  1.0min remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=2)]: Done   2 out of   2 | elapsed:  1.0min finished
[Parallel(n_jobs=2)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 2 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=2)]: Done   2 out of   2 | elapsed:    5.8s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=2)]: Done   2 out of   2 | elapsed:    5.8s finished
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ensemble.py", line 76, in <module>
    clf.fit(x_train_scaled)
  File "/home/ubuntu/thesis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyod/models/suod.py", line 220, in fit
    decision_score_mat, self.score_scalar_ = standardizer(
  File "/home/ubuntu/thesis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyod/utils/utility.py", line 152, in standardizer
    X = check_array(X)
  File "/home/ubuntu/thesis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 919, in check_array
    _assert_all_finite(
  File "/home/ubuntu/thesis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 161, in _assert_all_finite
    raise ValueError(msg_err)
ValueError: Input contains NaN.
```

and this is my code

```
train_data.dropna(axis=0)
test1_data.dropna(axis=0)
test2_data.dropna(axis=0)

mm_scaler = MinMaxScaler()

x_train_scaled = mm_scaler.fit_transform(train_data)
x_test2_scaled = mm_scaler.transform(test2_data)

x_test1_scaled = mm_scaler.transform(test1_data)

detector_list = [COPOD(), IForest(n_estimators=100,max_samples=10000, max_features=10,
                         bootstrap=True, n_jobs=-1, random_state=42),
                 IForest(n_estimators=200,max_samples=10000, max_features=10,
                         bootstrap=True, n_jobs=-1, random_state=42), ECOD(contamination=0.001)]

clf = SUOD(base_estimators=detector_list, n_jobs=2, combination='average',
           verbose=False)



clf.fit(x_train_scaled)


train_pred = clf.predict(x_train_scaled)
test_pred1 = clf.predict(x_test1_scaled)
test_pred2 = clf.predict(x_test2_scaled)
```

Thing that I have tried

1. SimpleImputer
2. dropping nan rows.
3. adding the mock patch

Answer (score 0):

As error output, you need to handle NaN values. `dropna` method return a new dataframe. If you want modify it, set parameter `inplace` to true and do operation inplace (return `None`),

> inplace : boolean, default False

So to modify it in place `data.dropna(axis=0, how='any', inplace=True)`

Also possible method to handle `NaN` values (this is optional and if applicable to your problem or a data mining related) is to convert `NaN` inputs to the median of the column `df = df.fillna(df.mean())`.

Another case (uncommon) is that your dataframe contains nan values represented as string type or `"NaN"`, then functions to manage nan values wont work, in that case you need to use something like `df.replace("NaN", numpy.nan)` and drop.